# Having Problem in implementng vue.js codes in my laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a fresh installation laravel app 
I have run all the required commands 
npm install and npm run dev and have included app.js file in my app.blade.php file 
but still the vue js is not working

My app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo Laravel Vue Chat</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div id="app">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item active">Group Name</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Type Your Message" class="form-control" v-model="message" @keyup.enter="send">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My webpack file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

My js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: '',
    },
    methods:{
        send()
        {
            console.log(this.message);
        }
    },
});
```

Stil the console is not giving output and the vue dev tool say vue js not detected

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add id app in body tag

```
<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: still not detected

Comment: he changed the question before editing he used 
        <div class="app"> this in is code and i corrected it

Answer (score -1):

You need to have id='app' in main wrapper. Your div wrappered by section tag and div with class container

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<div id="app">
   <example-componen></example-componen>
</div>
```